# angular 4.0.0 novalidate attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular

After migrating to angular 4 a strange issue with my template-driven form has occured. My `required` attr on input seems to be broken. I suppose that  has `novalidate` attribute by default. But I need some html5 validations. Tried `novalidate="false"` but had no success.
Is there some way to enable validation? Now it seems using reactive forms with its `Validators.required` is the only way.

Thanks!

My HTML component code snippet:

```
<form (submit)="savePhone(phone);" novalidate="false">
<h3>Новый телефон</h3>
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Номер телефона"
           onlyNumber="true" name="number"
           [(ngModel)]="phone.number" required>
</md-input-container>
<md-select placeholder="Источник получения" (ngModel)="phone.source" name="source">
    <md-option *ngFor="let source of sources" [value]="source">
        {{ source }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="Текст комментария"
          [(ngModel)]="phone.comment" name="comment">
</textarea>
<div layout="row" layout-align="end">
    <button class="button button--success" type="submit">
        Добавить
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To enable HTML5 validation use

```
<form (submit)="savePhone(phone);" ngNativeValidate>
```

See also [NgNoValidate source at GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_no_validate_directive.ts#L16)

Comment: Elaborating: Angular4 automatically adds `novalidate` in ngForm (your form tag) by default. As we know, `novalidate` disables HTML5 native browser validation. If you want to enable HTML5 validation, as @Günter said, add Angular's `ngNativeValidate` attribute in your form tag. Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15531

Comment: angular what the hell!